# Running a app-debug.apk or app-release.apk on Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am developing an application Android Studio 4.1.1 and debugging on a Samsung Galaxy S10.
I can successfully debug the application on the S10 from the Studio.

When I use the Studio to create an app-debug.apk or app-release.apk and use Apps -> Special Access -> Install unknown apps -> Cx File Explorer, I get the following:

a. Blocked by Play Protect ---> Install anyway

b. Package Installer - "Done" is highlighted, but "Open" is greyed out

c. Apps - shows the apk and its memory, etc but is not executable

I've tried most of the procedures shown in recent posts but with the same results.

How can I install the app on my phone to use and test without trying to go through Play Store?

[image: After "Install anyway"]

Comment: Did you find a solution for that I got the same error while uploading the release Apk on Galaxy store

Answer (score 0):

Somehow android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" got changed to android:name="***android.intent.action. MAIN***" in the AndroidManifest.xml.

A space between action. and MAIN